# Why token concatenation doesn't work in C++?

Tags: c++, struct, macros

I have the following piece of code and I want to programmatically access the fields of the struct:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#define FIELD(NAME, NUM)  {NAME##NUM}


struct SFOO
{
    int i;
    float   f1;
    float   f2;
    char    c;
};

int main() {
    printf("Offset of 'f1' is %u", offsetof(SFOO, f1));
    printf("Offset of 'f1' is %u", offsetof(SFOO, FIELD(f, 1)));
}
```

The first line in `main()` works but the second line doesn't compile (MSVC 2012). How can I generate the field name using token concatenation?

Comment: Why do you need the braces (`{}`) in the definition of `FIELD`?

Comment: The `FIELD` macro in the second line does not generate the same output as the first line.

Comment: Remove the braces `{}`?

Comment: @jxh Thanks. Can't believe I made such a dumb mistake. The code was copied from somewhere else so forgot to remove the brace.

Comment: For future reference, if something "doesn't compile", please include the copy-and-pasted error message in the question.

Comment: I hope you are aware that your code is C and not C++. This happens to be valid in C++, too, but In real C++ you would write this quite differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the `{` and `}` in your definition of `FIELD`.

```
#define FIELD(NAME, NUM)  NAME##NUM
```

With your previous definition, your print statement would expand into something that the `offsetof` macro won't accept:

```
    printf("Offset of 'f1' is %u", offsetof(SFOO, {f1}));
```